# Работа со словарями: вывод ключа и значений в которые этот ключ входит

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.5

Как проверить вхождение ключа в значение словаря? Длинна словаря любая
Когда я пробивал у меня проверялось вхождение ключа во все значения словаря.
Пример

```
>>> print(dic)
{1: [1, 5], 2: [1, 2], 3: [3, 4], 4: [3, 4], 5: [1, 5]}
>>> for items in dic.keys():
        for i in dic.values():
            print(items, i)
1 [1, 5], 1 [1, 2], 1 [3, 4], 1 [3, 4], 1 [1, 5], 2 [1, 5], 2 [1, 2], 2 [3, 4], 2 [3, 4], 2 [1, 5]
```

Дальше с 3, 4, и 5 тоже самое
Мне нужна только проверка ключ --> значение ключа, а не ключ --> значение КЛЮЧЕЙ

Меня интересует вывод ключа и значений в которые этот ключ входит т.е. для единицы должно вывести `1 [1, 5], 1 [1, 2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто перед печатью во вложенном цикле, проверьте что  ключ находится в значении: `if key in value: ..`.

Если значения в заданном словаре могут повторяться, то чтобы не печатать одинаковые пары `(ключ, значение)` несколько раз, можно убрать повторяющиеся значения, используя `set()`:

```
values = set(map(tuple, dic.values()))  # remove duplicates
for key in dic:
    for value in values: 
        if key in value:
            print(key, list(value))
```

#### Результат

```
1 [1, 2]
1 [1, 5]
2 [1, 2]
3 [3, 4]
4 [3, 4]
5 [1, 5]
```

Это кубический алгоритм `O(n*n*m)`, где `n` размер словаря, а `m` характеризует размер списков.

Можно квадратичный алгоритм получить `O(n*m + n*n)` (игнорируя шаги для `print()`):

```
values = {frozenset(v): v for v in dic.values()}  # remove duplicates
for key in dic:
    for value_set in values: 
        if key in value_set:
            print(key, values[value_set])
```

Вывод в этом случае тот же. В общем случае этот алгоритм игнорирует порядок чисел и повторы внутри значений (если есть как `[1, 2]` так и `[2, 1]` или `[1,2,2]` в значениях словаря, то только одно из них выводится).